# Expected value in an urn problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

In an urn there are $n$ red balls and $m$ blue balls. I extract them without replacement. Let $X$=time of first blue. What is $E(X)$?

I found PMF of $X$ and it is, if $k > n+1$

$$P(X=k) =\frac{n(n-1) \dots (n-k+1)m}{(m+n)(m+n-1) \dots (n+m-k+1)}$$

How could I evaluate $E(X)$?

Edit: I'm looking for an explicit form of $E(X)$

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Comment: By definition: $E[X] = \sum_{k}kP(X = k)$...If the PMF you found is true, then this should be the answer.

Comment: What is meant by 'time of first blue'?

Comment: @OriaGruber I don't think that the OP has troubles with definition of expectation.

Comment: Is the number of the extraction in which I extract the first blue ball

Comment: I am still confused by that is $X$ exactly. Do you mean it is the number of red balls preceding the first blue ball?

Comment: @StubbornAtom "plus one" If I understand well. The number of draws needed to get a blue ball.

Comment: Yes, is the number of draws needed to get the first blue ball

Comment: Similar questions:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75968/expectation-of-number-of-trials-before-success-in-an-urn-problem-without-replace?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74210/expected-number-of-draws-until-the-first-good-element-is-chosen.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, let there be $b$ blue balls and $r$ red ones.

By symmetry the gaps between the blue balls should be of equal length.  Thus the answer is $$\boxed{E[r,b]=\frac r{b+1
}+1}$$

Sanity check:  suppose there are $1$ red balls and $2$ blue ones.  Then the answer is $1$ with probability $\frac 23$ and $2$ with probability $\frac 13$ so $E=\frac 43$ and of course $\frac {1}{1+2}+1=\frac 43$.  More generally, with $1$ red and $b$ blue then the answer is $$E=1\times \frac b{b+1}+2\times (1-\frac b{b+1})=\frac {b+2}{b+1}=\frac 1{b+1}+1$$

Comment: @drhab Didn't look at your answer.  Will now.

Comment: @drhab  The recursion I see is $E[n,m]= \frac {m}{m+n}\times 1+ \frac n{m+n}\times (E[m-1,n]+1)$ .  Is this the same as yours?

Comment: @drhab  Ah, I think I've mangled $n,m$.  (why on earth wouldn't one use $r,b$?) I meant what you wrote.

Comment: @drhab Yes...I don't see what I am saying incorrectly, but I am increasingly unhappy with my result.  Seems to be wrong for $n=2,m=2$ for example.  Yet I am sure I have the symmetry principle right.  Will delete while I check.

Comment: @drhab the problem, as usual, is that I am an idiot.  I have corrected the error (though of course might have made others).

Comment: I will delete my comments and have a second look (or later perhaps). You are a what?... Well, if it comes to probability theory than I strongly disagree with that. I still am in fear that my answer could be wrong. If you find an error (don't feel forced to search for it) in it then please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I have found a mistake in mine. Working out of recursion is more complicated. It should have been $1+\frac{n}{n+m}+\frac{n}{n+m}\frac{n-1}{n-1+m}+\cdots$

Comment: You could have linked your answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170965/expected-value-of-number-of-removals-from-urn?rq=1) post or perhaps marked this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I am embarrassed to state that I didn't even recall my prior answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are $r$ red and $b$ blue balls. We define the random variables as

$X_1$ : number of red balls preceding the first blue ball.

$X_i$ : number of red balls drawn following the appearance of the $(i-1)$th blue but before the appearance of the $i$th blue ball,$\quad i=2,3,...$

$X_{b+1}:$ number of red balls drawn following the appearance of the $b$th blue.

So, $X_1+X_2+...+X_{b+1}=r$; note that the $(X_{i})_{i=1,2,...,b+1}$'s are identically distributed.

Thus from the linearity of expectation, $(b+1)\mathbb{E}(X_1)=r\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X_1)=\dfrac{r}{b+1}$

Now, let $Y:$ number of draws needed to get the first blue ball.

Then, $Y=X_1+1\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(X_1)+1$, which is the required answer.

---

We can also calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$ directly from the pmf

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=k)=\frac{b}{r+b}.\frac{(r)_k}{(r+b-1)_k}\quad,k=0,1,...,r$$

Comment: So...you agree the answer is just $\frac r{b+1}+1$ as follows from symmetry?

Comment: @lulu Believe it or not, my intuition is not that great to see the symmetry. Hence the crass analytical approach.

Comment: Oh, that's not my point at all.  I just was confused by your answer.  Wanted to confirm that you were agreeing with the basic formula.

Comment: @lulu Of course our final answers are correct.

Comment: For intuition:  suppose that there was one Green marble and that the marbles were arrayed in a necklace.  Then you'd agree that the strings of reds should have the same expected length.  And there are $b+1$ strings of reds.  That's the entire symmetry argument.